# Keyboard shortcut for switching screens using synergy

Tags: synergy

I work much more efficiently when I don't have to take my hands off the keyboard.  I know that others do as well.

I found three issues in the synergy tracking system requesting a hotkey for switching screens: issues [866](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/866), [915](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/915), and [2279](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/2279).  All three issues are **closed** as a duplicate of a mysterious *RFE 702597*.  Where is this secret enhancement request?  What's its status?

Who else would find mouse-free operation helpful?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [old config guide](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html) (page now deleted, but [archived at the Way Back Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511090800/http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html)) you can achieve this with config options like this:

```
keystroke(alt+left) = switchInDirection(left)
keystroke(shift+control+alt+super) = switchToScreen(moe)
```

Comment: Excellent.  So it does.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Confirmed works with 1.4.10, with a Mac slave on a Windows host. Excellent!

Comment: I dont get it.. why nothing happens here??

Comment: Still works. Just to confirm, I put mine in my `section: options` - I used `keystroke(alt+super+right) = switchInDirection(right)` (and another for left) and then restarted my `synergys` - a it all works beautifully!

Answer (score 8):

This functionality can be added on the windows version by launching Synergy from the start menu and selecting "HotKeys" from the options pane.

Comment: Note that this hotkeys pane is now in the Servers... screen